# How can I connect these dots?

Tags: modeling, texturing, bones, customization, selection-tools

First of all , I'm very new to Blender . I'm making some changes on a blend. I want them connect to each other like magnet . How can I connect these two dots without any gaps between them like the those next to it ? [image]

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple ways to do it, one the easiest is:

- in edit mode, select the 2 dots (called vertex in 3d)
  (you need to be in vertex select mode: press <kbd>1</kbd> to be sure to be in
  this mode)
- press <kbd>F3</kbd> (to search for a command) and write "merge"
- choose this option:  Mesh > Merge (M) >  At center

If you want to skip the F3 thing, you can select the 2 dots and press <kbd>M</kbd> and then select the option you prefer (at center should be the best in your scenario).

Answer (score 1):

You can activate the *Snap* option (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> when you move your vertex) in *Vertex* mode, and activate also the *Auto Merge* option:

[image]

Or select your vertices and <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge*, and choose the option your want:

[image]

Comment: Alt-M ? on my blender it's just M

Comment: I never know, the weird thing is that I sometimes here people say M but in my Preferences it seems to be Alt M... I'm going to edit though...

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/merge.html

Comment: So I may have changed the shortcut, but why don't I have the Reset arrow in my Preferences? https://zupimages.net/up/21/30/ouhi.jpg

Comment: this is my setting --> https://pasteboard.co/KdVDa1N.png, 
if i change it adding the ALT, this is the ui --> https://pasteboard.co/KdVDz5g.png

Comment: Yes, strange, I think that for all the custom shortcuts that I've created I also have the Restore button, so what's happening here? I've already noticed that people use M

Comment: It's just M on my Mac

Comment: ok, if anyone knows how this is possible that I don't have a Restore button, I'm interested

Comment: @moonboots open your own questions :) (maybe it's just a version problem of your blender or customization you don't know)

Comment: Ok I will....  ;)